# Drawing chart with jQuery and Flot Plugin

Tags: jquery, mysql, css, graph, flot

```
 <?php

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $dataset1[] = array($row['dateReport'],$row['totalUniqueView']);
        }

        echo json_encode($dataset1);
    ?>

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Graph scripts here.

        var graphData = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;
```

Hi guys, I need help over here. I had manage to follow the tutorials here: http://designmodo.com/create-interactive-graph-css3-jquery/

and it's working perfectly. I tried to modify it so that it can read data from my database. As you can see from the above codes, I have change and add a few php line and modify the script. However, it's not working, it returns weird data to my graph. Please help.

Comment: please post the contents of json_encode($dataset1);

Comment: [["2013-08-23","427"],["2013-08-24","679"],["2013-08-25","678"],["2013-08-26","1030"],["2013-08-27","1145"],["2013-08-28","1241"],["2013-08-29","1265"],["2013-08-30","1292"]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there are a couple of issues with your data there.

Firstly, dates/times must be provided in the form of a JavaScript timestamp; excerpt from [the docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md):

> The time series support in Flot is based on Javascript timestamps,
>   i.e. everywhere a time value is expected or handed over, a Javascript
>   timestamp number is used. This is a number, not a Date object. A
>   Javascript timestamp is the number of milliseconds since January 1,
>   1970 00:00:00 UTC. This is almost the same as Unix timestamps, except
>   it's in milliseconds, so remember to multiply by 1000!

Secondly, your data is enclosed in quotes, meaning it is being passed as a string rather than a number - this will stop Flot being able to correctly plot the data. From [the FAQ](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/FAQ.md):

> Flot isn't working when I'm using JSON data as source!
>
> Actually, Flot loves JSON data, you just got the format wrong. Double
>   check that you're not inputting strings instead of numbers, like
>   [["0", "-2.13"], ["5", "4.3"]]. This is most common mistake, and the
>   error might not show up immediately because Javascript can do some
>   conversion automatically.

You should be able to fix both of these issues by generating your data something like this:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array(strtotime($row['dateReport']) * 1000, (int)$row['totalUniqueView']);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... This really helps alot... I can see my graph now... The only thing now is that my date is messed up. I got this now... [[1377216000000,427],[1377302400000,679],[1377388800000,678],[1377475200000,1030],[1377561600000,1145],[1377648000000,1241],[1377734400000,1265],[1377820800000,1292]]

Comment: My date format is in this format '2013-10-09'... The graph must display in integer ? Thanks.. That's the last thing to fix.

Comment: That's what the `strtotime()*1000` bit does, it converts your dates in to the required JavaScript formatted timestamp (total seconds since Jan 1 1970). Try setting the tick size on your `xaxis: { tickSize: [1, "day"] }`. In what way does it look messed up?

Comment: I've added the ticksize, but still not working... The x-axis doesnt shows anything... However if I removed it. The x-axis is showing those long numbers e.g 1377216000000, and so on...

Comment: If possible, could you copy all codes from here: http://designmodo.com/create-interactive-graph-css3-jquery/ and convert it to read from database, and base on date on x-axis? It would be much easier for you to help me out... Thank you so much... I could send you the code if you're able to give me you email address...

Comment: Oh right ok.. you want the long numbers, you just need to change the time format, add this to your xaxis code:  `timeformat: "%d/%m",`

Comment: by the way, if you are doing time based graphs, you need to include the `jquery.flot.time.js` javascript file as well as the standard flot.js file

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is solved, I finally got what I needed. I used this: "mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d/%y", minTickSize: [1, "day"]" and included this "jquery.flot.time.js" and everything works!

Comment: Ah, the one thing I forgot! But excellent, I knew you were close :)